# facebook like got me crazy

Tags: facebook, prestashop

my prestashop facebook like button keep giving me ERROR in red no matter what i do.

I have my facebook like set up successfully if i do this

```
<iframe src=“http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://URL.com&layout=standard&show_faces=false&width=450&action=like&font=verdana&colorscheme=light&height=35” scrolling=“no” frameborder=“0” style=“border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;” allowTransparency=“true”></iframe>
```

However, this above post this problems:

1) It post a static url as URL.com to my facebook whenver the LIKE is clicked. How do i make the url to be dynamic according to the product page currently viewed?

2) Whenever i click LIKE, my facebook wall will delete the previous product which i like and add the latest one to the top.

3) How do i get the exact picture which i click LIKE posted to facebook?

---

To solved the dynamic URL for question (1), i then try this from [here](http://www.econtentsite.com/Prestashop/facebook-like-button-for-prestashop-product-pages.html). However it then post me error after the button is clicked.

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href={php} echo 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; {/php}&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom: 0px"></iframe>
```

I have done some research on the successful website for this feature such as [this](http://www.prodaja-nakita.rs/product.php?id_product=129). When i view the page source it has this as below:

`<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://www.prodaja-nakita.rs/product.php?id_product=129&amp;
layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
 allowTransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom: 0px"></iframe>`

I have exactly the same as it when i do a compare with my url page source.

As for the question (3), if it cannot get me the exact picture, i would prefer something like [This](http://www.luveit.com/maxi-dresses/45-day-night-pleated-feather-maxi-dress.html) where it allow user to select which picture to choose. ** CLick on the facebook share to test it out.

I have even tried install V1.1.1 facebook like button from [here](http://www.presto-changeo.com/en/prestashop-free-modules/45-facebook-like-button.html%20for%20prestashop%201.3.7) but still having same problem.
FYI, i am using prestashop 1.3.7. In order to get this facebook like button to work, i have uninstalled the chrononical Url, turned off the friendly URL feature. whewwww....

Somebody please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out that it is because of the Ip address you key in when your page is offline.
Remove the ip and enable the shop and the like button works great